# Get the text of hyperlink in gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, hyperlink

I have converted some text to hyperlinks  in gridview.

```
if (e.Row.Cells[3].Text == Session["uname"].ToString())
{
    e.Row.BackColor = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#FFFFCC");
    e.Row.Cells[1].Text = "<a href='Service.aspx'>"+e.Row.Cells[1].Text+"</a>";            
}
```

I want to get the text from the hyperlinks when clicked and store in the session variable.
Can anyone help me doing this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One easy trick is to add it as parameter to you link and when you call that `service.aspx` page to save it on your session.

For example:

```
String.Format("<a href='Service.aspx?TextLink={1}'>{0}</a>"
      , e.Row.Cells[1].Text
      ,  Server.UrlEncode(e.Row.Cells[1].Text)
      );
```

Now on the `service.aspx` on `Page_Load` you add

```
if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString["TextLink"]))
    session["hyp"] = Request.QueryString["TextLink"];
```

One other way is to capture with javascript the link and do the same with ajax.

Comment: Thank for the reply.Can you please tell me where  is the  text stored?

Comment: @SandraDsouza Is not stored anywhere, is just passed with the url as parameter, and you need to add it to the session when you call the `Service.aspx`

Comment: sorry to ask you again. session["hyp"]=??.  I'm not familiar with the code that you have given. Thank you so much for the help

Answer (score 0):

Hey If you want to do from Server side code then you have to change "" to Server Linkbutton control then only you can get link code on Grid Row Command event . Please refer this code to get link value.

```
protected void gvNewJoineeDetails_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {

            if (!e.CommandSource.GetType().Name.Contains("GridView"))
            {

                GridViewRow row1 = (GridViewRow)(((LinkButton)e.CommandSource).NamingContainer);

                LinkButton lnkCust1 = (LinkButton)row1.FindControl("gvlnkBtnNewJoineeDetails");
```

}
}

Or if you do not change your logic means you do not take link button instead of 'a' then you can get value it on client side by Jquery and set to hidden field and access in server side or make ajax call to send value in server side.

For Client Side get value use Jquery. please refer this code.

```
$("a").live("click", function (e) {
            var getvalue = $(this).text();

        });
```

Comment: is not say anywhere for jQuery.